# SQL Server : error creating table with multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, primary-key

Query is as follows:

```
create TABLE tbl_temp (
[ref] numeric(18), 
[item_code] varchar(50), 
[item_desc] nvarchar(150),
[Qty] smallint) PRIMARY KEY (ref, item_code))
```

Returning error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: To be picky: it's not **multiple** primary keys that you have - it's **one** primary key, made up from **multiple** columns. You cannot ever have truly **multiple** primary keys - that's just not possible

Comment: I am familiar with that :) Blame the silly title on the syntax and my struggle with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```
create TABLE tbl_temp 
(
   [ ref] numeric(18), 
   [item_code] varchar(50), 
   [item_desc] nvarchar(150),
   [Qty] smallint,
   PRIMARY KEY (ref, item_code)
)
```

But better way to do that is to use `constraint` as below:

```
create TABLE tbl_temp 
(
   [ ref] numeric(18), 
   [item_code] varchar(50), 
   [item_desc] nvarchar(150),
   [Qty] smallint,
   CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_temp  PRIMARY KEY (ref, item_code)
)
```

or

```
create TABLE tbl_temp 
(
   [ ref] numeric(18), 
   [item_code] varchar(50), 
   [item_desc] nvarchar(150),
   [Qty] smallint
) 

ALTER TABLE tbl_temp 
 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_temp  PRIMARY KEY (ref, item_code)
```

Is better way because you set a friendly name for your PK.

Comment: You can set name in the first example too. Just add CONSTRAINT pk_name in front of PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Rather try

```
create TABLE tbl_temp
([ref] numeric(18), 
 [item_code] varchar(50),
 [item_desc] nvarchar(150),
 [Qty] smallint,
PRIMARY KEY (ref, item_code)
 )
```

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ac15)